# Find the REST request of a form

Tags: google-chrome-devtools

Using developer tools, how do you properly inspect a form properties ?
More specifically, is there a way to see the POST request a form submit button will send ?

Comment: have you tried `Inspect Elements`?

Comment: @SaadAnees yes, I can see the form properties, but I was hoping to get the json post payload, including potentially hidden form values